# Create rewrite rule for subpage

Tags: url-rewriting

I want to add a dynamic page for every page that has URL subpage of "/team".

How would I configure "add_rewrite_rule" regex expression to allow me that?

Example:

```
path: http://page.com/business/team
rewrite: http://page.com/index.php?department-team=business

path: http://page.com/hr/team
rewrite: http://page.com/index.php?department-team=hr
```

Code I'm working with:

```
add_action('query_vars', 'department_team_add_query_vars');
add_action('init', 'department_team_add_rewrite_rules');
add_filter('template_include', 'department_team_template_include');


function department_team_add_query_vars($vars)
{
    $vars[] = 'department-team';

    return $vars;
}

function department_team_add_rewrite_rules()
{
    // do I need this?
    //add_rewrite_tag('%department-team%', '([^&]+)');

    // rewrite url to
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '/([^/]*)/team',
        'index.php?department-team=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}

function department_team_template_include($template)
{
    global $wp_query;
    $new_template = '';

    var_dump(array_key_exists('department-team', $wp_query->query_vars));
    var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);

    if (array_key_exists('department-team', $wp_query->query_vars)) {
        switch ($wp_query->query_vars['department-team']) {
            case 'team':
                $new_template = locate_template(['department_team.php']);

                break;
        }

        if ($new_template != '') {
            var_dump('aaa');
            die();

            return $new_template;
        }
        else {
            $wp_query->set_404();

            status_header(404);

            return get_404_template();
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar.  I have a page (country_tc) that uses a custom page template that either dynamically generates info for requested country, or a series of sub-pages for the country e.g.

`/country/Egypt` (*index.php?pagename=country&countrytc=egypt*)

`/country/egypt/safety` (*index.php?pagename=country&countrytc=egypt/safety*)

I use **page_rewrite_rules** for the re-write. I've not had time to vet your code, so this is how I'd do it:

In a site functions **plugin**:

```
//  allow WP to store querystring attribs for use in our pages
function tc_query_vars_filter($vars) {
  $vars[] = 'department-team';
  $vars[] .= 'another-var';
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'tc_query_vars_filter' );

function tc_rewrite_rules($rules) {
   global $wp_rewrite;
   $tc_rule = array(
     // working example from my site
     'country/(.+)/?' => 'index.php?pagename=' . 'country' . '&countrytc=$matches[1]',
     // YOUR rule (not tested)
     '/([^/]*)/team', 'index.php?pagename=YOURPAGENAME&department-team=$matches[1]'
   );
   return array_merge($tc_rule, $rules);
}
add_filter('page_rewrite_rules', 'tc_rewrite_rules');
```

**AFTER ACTIVATING PLUGIN YOU NEED TO RE-SAVE PERMALINKS ON DASHBOARD - THIS WILL FLUSH/UPDATE YOUR REWRITE RULES**

Do the rest of your code **in your custom page** using:

`get_query_var('department-team')` - sanitize, validate do your includes as required.

Answer (score 0):

Use `add_rewrite_endpoint` instead, it generates the rules for you.

```
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'team', EP_PAGES );
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm implkementing this correctly as `department-team` is still not located in `$wp_query->query_vars`.

Comment: it would be `team` in this case, the query var has the same name as the endpoint.